# How to convert timedelta to time of day in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, timedelta

I have a SQL table that contains data of the mySQL `time` type as follows:

```
time_of_day
-----------
   12:34:56
```

I then use `pandas` to read the table in:

`df = pd.read_sql('select * from time_of_day', engine)`

Looking at `df.dtypes` yields:

`time_of_day    timedelta64[ns]`

My main issue is that, when writing my `df` to a csv file, the data comes out all messed up, instead of essentially looking like my SQL table:

```
time_of_day
0 days 12:34:56.000000000
```

**I'd like to instead (obviously) store this record as a `time`, but I can't find anything in the pandas docs that talk about a time `dtype`.**

Does pandas lack this functionality intentionally? Is there a way to solve my problem without requiring janky data casting?

Seems like this should be elementary, but I'm confounded.

Comment: what does pandas.to_datetime give?

Comment: it returns `1970-01-01 12:34:56`

Comment: Same issue when mysql column is of type TIME, pandas return TimeDelta. I do not get this behavior when the column type is DATETIME. There's not option in Pandas read_sql method to parse the TIME.

Comment: The issue I think is NumPy hasn't implemented a `time` class, and Pandas is built on NumPy. So don't think this is natural for Pandas.

Answer (score 4):

#### Pandas does not support a `time` dtype series

Pandas (and NumPy) do not have a `time` dtype. Since you wish to avoid Pandas `timedelta`, you have 3 options: Pandas [`datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), Python [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects), or Python [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str). Below they are presented in order of preference. Let's assume you start with the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.to_timedelta(['12:34:56', '05:12:45', '15:15:06'])})

print(df['time'].dtype)  # timedelta64[ns]
```

#### Pandas `datetime` series

You can use Pandas `datetime` series and include an arbitrary date component, e.g. today's date. Underlying such a series are integers, which makes this solution the most efficient and adaptable.

The default date, if unspecified, is 1-Jan-1970:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

print(df)

#                  time
# 0 1970-01-01 12:34:56
# 1 1970-01-01 05:12:45
# 2 1970-01-01 15:15:06
```

You can also specify a date, such as today:

```
df['time'] = pd.Timestamp('today').normalize() + df['time']

print(df)

#                  time
# 0 2019-01-02 12:34:56
# 1 2019-01-02 05:12:45
# 2 2019-01-02 15:15:06
```

#### Pandas `object` series of Python `datetime.time` values

The Python `datetime` module from the standard library supports `datetime.time` objects. You can convert your series to an `object` dtype series containing pointers to a sequence of `datetime.time` objects. Operations will no longer be vectorised, but each underlying value will be represented internally by a number.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.time

print(df)

#        time
# 0  12:34:56
# 1  05:12:45
# 2  15:15:06

print(df['time'].dtype)
# object

print(type(df['time'].at[0]))
# <class 'datetime.time'>
```

#### Pandas `object` series of Python `str` values

Converting to strings is only recommended for presentation purposes that are not supported by other types, e.g. Pandas `datetime` or Python `datetime.time`. For example:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

print(df)

#        time
# 0  12:34:56
# 1  05:12:45
# 2  15:15:06

print(df['time'].dtype)
# object

print(type(df['time'].at[0]))
# <class 'str'>
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` no longer works in pandas 1.0.

Comment: @jebob, Docs suggest otherwise: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: that page makes no mention of timedeltas?

Comment: @jebob, Neither does your previous comment!

Comment: Whatever the docs say the error message is clear: `TypeError: dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]`

Answer (score 1):

it's a hack, but you can pull out the components to create a string and convert that string to a datetime.time(h,m,s) object

```
def convert(td):
    time = [str(td.components.hours), str(td.components.minutes), 
    str(td.components.seconds)]
    return datetime.strptime(':'.join(time), '%H:%M:%S').time()

df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: convert(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution, but i feel like it's gotta be more elegant than this:

```
def convert(x):
    return pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%H:%M:%S')

df['time_of_day'] = df['time_of_day'].apply(convert)
```

Comment: `TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> is not convertible to datetime`

Answer (score -1):

```
df['time_of_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_of_day']).apply(lambda x: x.time())
```

[Adapted this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41796793/940592)