# How do I convert timestamp to datetime.date in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

I need to merge 2 pandas dataframes together on dates, but they currently have different date types. 1 is timestamp (imported from excel) and the other is `datetime.date`.

Any advice?

I've tried `pd.to_datetime().date` but this only works on a single item(e.g. `df.ix[0,0]`), it won't let me apply to the entire series (e.g. `df['mydates']`) or the dataframe.

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df['mydates'])

Comment: Hi @piRSquared. That doesn't work unfortunately. pd.todatetime(df['my_dates']) still returns pandas.tslib.Timestamp when i access 1 element in the series (e.g. if i save that off as a new DataFrame as df2, type(df2.ix[0,0]) will still return Timestamp), and i need it to be datetime.date

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I got some help from a colleague.

This appears to solve the problem posted above

`pd.to_datetime(df['mydates']).apply(lambda x: x.date())`

Answer (score 47):

Much simpler than above:

```
df['mydates'].dt.date
```

Answer (score 15):

For me this works:

```
from datetime import datetime
df[ts] = [datetime.fromtimestamp(x) for x in df[ts]]
```

Answer (score 14):

You have to know if the unit of the Unix timestamp is in seconds or milliseconds. Assume that it is in seconds and assume that you have the following pandas

```
print(df.head())
```

And you get:

```
     timestamp XETHZUSD
0  1609459200   730.85
1  1609545600   775.01
2  1609632000   979.86
3  1609718400  1042.52
4  1609804800  1103.41
```

You can convert the timestamp to datetime as follows:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')

print(df.head())
```

And we get:

```
   timestamp XETHZUSD
0 2021-01-01   730.85
1 2021-01-02   775.01
2 2021-01-03   979.86
3 2021-01-04  1042.52
4 2021-01-05  1103.41
```

If the Unix timestamp was in milliseconds, then you should have typed

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
```

Comment: This part of the code worked perfeclt 
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
Easy solution, one line to write.

Comment: This one's the best solution since it also maintains the original timezone of data

Answer (score 6):

Another question was marked as dupe pointing to this, but it didn't include this answer, which seems the most straightforward (perhaps this method did not yet exist when this question was posted/answered):

The pandas doc shows a [`pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime.html) method to "Convert a Timestamp object to a native Python datetime object".

Answer (score 3):

Assume time column is in timestamp integer msec format

1 day = 86400000 ms

Here you go:

```
day_divider = 86400000

df['time'] = df['time'].values.astype(dtype='datetime64[ms]') # for msec format

df['time'] = (df['time']/day_divider).values.astype(dtype='datetime64[D]') # for day format
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the `datetime.date` objects... then get them through with the `.date` attribute of the `Timestamp`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['mydates']).date
```

Comment: That does not appear to work either. 

This, however, does the trick `pd.to_datetime(df['mydates']).apply(lambda x: x.date())`

Comment: If the input is a series with a single row, `s.date.date()` worked for me.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['mydates']).dt.date` - this should work

Answer (score 1):

I found the following to be the most effective, when I ran into a similar issue. For instance, with the dataframe `df` with a series of timestmaps in column `ts`.

```
df.ts.apply(lambda x: pd.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).date())
```

This makes the conversion, you can leave out the `.date()` suffix for datetimes. Then to alter the column on the dataframe. Like so...

```
df.loc[:, 'ts'] = df.ts.apply(lambda x: pd.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).date())
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to convert a timestamp column to date/time, here is what I came up with:

```
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda timestamp: datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp))
```