Extract date from timestamp column in a dataframe in python
How to extract date only from a timestamp column in a dataframe in python?

I believe that your question is answered here I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/41796793/25348441

Does this answer your question? How do I convert timestamp to datetime.date in pandas dataframe?
