# How to get average of column which is derived as difference between 'Created Date' and 'Closed Date' in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datetime columns , "Created Date" and "Closed Date". I subtracted to get resolution time which shows time-delta in days. Now I want to see average for resolution time for all rows. How do I go that?

My code so far

```
df['resolution_time'] = df['Closed Date'] - df['Created Date']
```

Now I want average of the entire df['resolution_time] column.
I tried the code below:

```
df['resolution_time'].mean()
```

The result I received was

```
Timedelta('0 days 05:40:26.569837941')
```

I have no clue how to interpret this result?

Comment: Have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501930/how-to-convert-timedelta-to-time-of-day-in-pandas

Comment: what units do you want.  docs are simple: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html