# Python xlwings - TypeError: must be real number, not Timedelta

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

I have a pandas dataframe containing columns in timedelta64[ns] format.
For this project I cannot use df.to_excel() and I need to import the dataframe via xlwings so that it prints into existing Excel Workbook and keeps its format.

When I try the usual:

```
workbook_sablona_dochazka.sheets[zamestnanec].range('A1').options(index=False).value = individual_dochazka_zamestnanec
```

I receive error:
TypeError: must be real number, not Timedelta

Is there a way to format my timedelta64[ns] so that xlwings would be able to import the dataframe in? I need to preserve my time values so that it becomes 12:30:00 in Excel again after xlwings import and maybe some after-formatting inside the Excel itself.

I tried:

```
individual_dochazka_zamestnanec['Příchod do práce'] = individual_dochazka_zamestnanec['Příchod do práce'].values.astype(float)
```

This worked around the error but imported columns had totally out of sense numbers.

Any idea how to work around this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the error says it's a "TimeDelta", then you have to ask delta relative to what?  Usually a TimeDelta indicates something like "three hours" or "minus two days".  You say you'd like the output to be "12:30:00" is that an actual time or does it mean 12 hours 30 minutes and no seconds?

You could try making the TimeDelta relative to "the beginning of time" so that it's a date which can be imported into xlwings but is formatted like a time as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501930/how-to-convert-timedelta-to-time-of-day-in-pandas).

Comment: Hello doug, thank you for trying to help. I went through the question post you suggested and tried every single thing there. For all the cases, I am getting the same error: dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to figure it out.

The trick was to first format timedelta64[ns] columns as string and then trim it a bit with `.map(lambda x:str(x)[7:]))` so that I would get that nice time only stamp.

```
individual_dochazka_zamestnanec['Počet odpracovaných hodin celkem'] = ((individual_dochazka_zamestnanec['Počet odpracovaných hodin celkem']).astype(str)).map(lambda x: str(x)[7:])
```

To my surprise, Excel accepted this without issue which is exactly what I needed.

Hope this helps someone, sometime.

Cheers!